# How to execute only one form action method in asp.net mvc view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this page that contains 2 forms one exists in the layout file and the other in the view file. The first form is for newsletter subscription (an ajax form) and its location is common in the footer of the page, that's why it's in the layout and is rendered as a partial view. I have another view of the contact us page with its own form (normal form).
My issue is when I submit the contact us form, the code also goes into the action method of the subscription form and returns a model error with JsonResult causing the whole view to be rendered as text. I only want the action method of the contact us form to be executed.

Here is the subscription form in a partial view file

```
@model MyApp.Models.Subscriber
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("NewsletterSubscription", "Shared", null, new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        OnBegin = "OnBegin",
        OnComplete = "OnComplete",
        OnFailure = "OnFailure"
    }, new { id = "subscribeForm" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SubscriptionEmail)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SubscriptionEmail)
        <input id="btnSubscribe" type="submit" value="Subscribe" />
    }
```

And this is how it's rendered in the _layout.cshtml file

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("NewsletterSubscription", "Shared"); }
```

Here's the other form in contactus view file

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Contact", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "contactForm" }))
     {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
         <div class="theForm">
             <div class="theFormUnit">
                 <p>Fullname</p>
                 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)
                 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
             </div>
             <div class="theFormUnit">
                 <p>Email</p>
                 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email)
                 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
             </div>
             <div class="theFormUnit">
                 <p>Phone</p>
                 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Phone)
                 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phone)
             </div>
             <div class="theFormUnit">
                 <p>Message</p>
                 @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Message)
                 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Message)
             </div>
             <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </div>
     }
```

When I debug the code, first the action method of the contact us is executed then the action method of the subscription and returns an error since the email was not provided.

The subscription action method

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult NewsletterSubscription(Subscriber subscriber)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
    }
    else
    {
       return Json(new { success = false, message = "Failure Message" });
    }

    return Json(new { success = true, message = "Success Message"}); 
}
```

And contact us action method

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
 public ActionResult Index(ContactViewModel contact)
 {
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
    }
    else
    {
    }
    return View(contact);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the layout form is not rendering in you contact form? First check the view source of the page to ensure the forms are not nested.

Comment: I've already checked that, the forms are not nested, both forms are rendered correctly with other html elements in between.

Comment: hmm in that case may be some JavaScript is doing this. Did you use these form elements in any js as you gave them separate ids?

Comment: No I am not using them in any js, at first I didn't assign any ids to the forms then I thought this might be what's causing the problem and may be if there are multiple forms then each should have an id but when I added them nothing changed, I got the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I tried two solutions the first one partially solved the problem and the other solved it completely.

First solution was to add the following lines in the action method of the subscription form

```
if (!Request.IsAjaxRequest())
{
 ModelState.Clear();
 return PartialView("Partial/_NewsletterSubscription");
}
```

Here I am checking if the request is not an ajax request, which means it's the postback request for the contact us form, in this case I clear the model state to remove the error and return a new partial view. Although this solution solved the issue but I wasn't satisfied with it because I was not convinced with the fact that action method of the subscription form gets executed with the action method of the contact us form.

So later I thought of another simple solution, which totally solved the issue and the execution doesn't go into the action method of the subscription form when submitting the contact us form. 
I simply changed the action method name from "NewsletterSubscription" to "Subscribe" so instead of

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("NewsletterSubscription", "Shared", null, new AjaxOptions
```

I changed it to

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Subscribe", "Shared", null, new AjaxOptions
```